# Weird results when compiling in release mode

Tags: class, opengl, vector, release, mode

I've written a Vector class that I use for my 3D "engine". It works just like intended when compiled in debug mode but when compiled in release mode the colors are completely wrong. Instead of being the colors I specified it becomes a solid color that changes with the camera :s.

I've taken pictures to show how it looks like: [debug mode](http://localhostr.com/file/R4nX4ve/debugmode.PNG) and [release mode](http://localhostr.com/file/KwlU5w5/releasemode.PNG). Note that I also use this class for transforming my vertices and that works fine in both debug and release mode.

This is how I pass the color vectors to my shader (pseudocode).

```
Vector3 Diffuse = Vector3(0.3f, 0.5f, 1.0f);
Vector3 Ambient = Vector3(0.3f, 0.3f, 0.3f);

Shaders.SetUniformData("AmbientColor", sizeof(float) * 3, 1, &Ambient);
Shaders.SetUniformData("DiffuseColor", sizeof(float) * 3, 1, &Diffuse);
```

Please tell if you need to see more code.

And here is my Vector class source code: http://pastebin.com/spy7FWFg  (had to remove the http:// because I'm only allowed to post 2 hyper links).
This have been bothering me for a while so any help is much appreciated.

**EDIT**: Alright I solved it! Heh it was nothing wrong with the Vector class it was how I sent it to the shaders...

The thing is I have 2 functions I've made to pass data to the shaders, the first is the one I showed in the first post and the other (which I was using for real) takes an array of UNIFORM structs (custom struct) and apparently that one didn't work during release mode...

Sorry for wasting your time and thanks for your help =)

Comment: Your Vector class looks perfectly sane for me. As this is happening only in release mode, go and look out (or hunt for) uninitialized variables in all of your code (usually in debug mode variables get initialized which they don't in release mode).

Comment: How about providing us with the source code of the vector class itself? Otherwise it's just guesswork, what's not being initialized properly.

Comment: @datenwolf The source code is linked in my post you probably just missed it because it's in plain text and not as a real link. Here it is again though: http://pastebin.com/spy7FWFg

Comment: @Traxmate: Indeed. I made it a link.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with cli_hlt, the first thing to look for are uninitialized variables anywhere in your code. One other, somewhat unlikely though is that you might try storing your ambient and diffuse colors in a straight `float[]` before passing them in:

```
float diffuseArray[] = { Diffuse.X,Diffuse.Y,Diffuse.Z };
float ambientArray[] = { Ambient.X,Ambient.Y,Diffuse.Z };
Shaders.SetUniformData("AmbientColor", sizeof(float) * 3, 1, ambientArray);
Shaders.SetUniformData("DiffuseColor", sizeof(float) * 3, 1, diffuseArray);
```

As is, you are working under the (quite reasonable, I think) assumption that all your Vector's member variables show up in memory, in order, in the first 12 bytes of your Vector object, so passing in a pointer to the vector should be equivalent to passing in an array of three `float`s. I believe this is generally valid, but it might be worth trying if you are certain the problem is occurring in the given lines of code.

Comment: Doing it like that do work but it's a bit tedious... I've checked if it's in order by putting a breakpoint to get the address and then checking with Cheat Engine and it's in order as this picture shows: http://localhostr.com/file/RvgSnMw/cheat%20engine%20values.PNG
It shouldn't be a problem with uninitialized variables since the class auto initialized all variables to 0 but then again all this is kinda new to me so I may be wrong :P

Comment: Since it works when you do it that way, why don't you just create a method in your vertex class that returns a float array so that you don't have to explicitly grab each component?